# implementing an accessor for a static variable in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, implementation, static-methods

I'm a CS student and right now we're learning about inheritance. For our assignments, the teacher gives us a main.cpp file and a class header. We're expected to create a .cpp implementation of the header without altering the given files. I've done most of it, but here's what I can't implement:

```
// File: employee.h

class Employee : public Person
{
private:
  static Company company;

public:
  static Company GetCompany();
  static void SetCompany(const Company& company);
}
```

It's the [static void SetCompany] that I'm unable to work with. Normally in the implementation I'd just do

```
//  File: employee.cpp

void Employee::SetCompany(const Company& company) { this->company = company; }
```

but I get the error "'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function". I'm not really sure how else I'm supposed to assign the variable, and it was never addressed in class. Any help would be appreciated. Just note that this is pretty much the format I'm expected to keep, so hopefully any advice won't stray too much. Anyway, thanks in advance and let me know if anything needs to be clarified... or if I'm just being blind and/or stupid about this.

Comment: your teacher never mentioned that static members can be called by their full names, in this case Company::company? That's quite an oversight.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in my original post. It was supposed to be Employee::SetCompany, not Company::Company. I'm still not sure how I'm supposed to use it. And yeah, my teacher tends to rush through pseudocode on a powerpoint without any real explanation. Anyway, thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access a static field, use `Employee::company`, as you cant use `this` because it is meant to refer to an instance of a class.

Your setter will become

```
void Employee::SetCompany(const Company& company) { 
  Employee::company = company; 
}
```

But if you try to simply replace your setter, your compiler will throw an error, saying that it doesn't know `Employee::company`. Because it is not instantiate. You need, in your .cpp file, as you would do with a function to declare your field with

```
Company Employee::company;
```

Answer (score 1):

For static variables, you just refer to the class variable and not an instance.

```
void Employee::SetCompany(const Company& company) {
    Employee::company = company;
}
```

Comment: Employee::company = company; but close enough. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the earlier comment, you can refer to static members with their full name, for example `Employee::company`. So, you should be able to fix your example by simply changing the function to this :

```
static void SetCompany(const Company& company) { Employee::company = company; }
```

This is because static member variables are independent of a particular instance of the class. The `this` keyword refers to the specific instance of the class. So, by changing a static member, all instantiations of the class have this change.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important for you to understand the compiler's and language scoping rules.  When a method (static or otherwise) has a PARAMETER that has a name "company", but the class has an accessible MEMBER (static or otherwise) that has a name "company", what are the rules for resolving the bare name "company"?  What if there was no parameter named company, how can/should you reference the member?

Here's another wrinkle - what if there is a LOCAL parameter named company?

```
void Employee::CompareCompany(const Company &company)
{
  Company company("another company");
  // which company is being referenced on the LHS (left hand side)
  // of the == expression below? The method parameter or the local variable?
  if (company == Employee::company)
    stout << "They match!"
}
```

Do you think this is a good idea for me to keep using the same name?  They're all instances of Company, so why isn't "company" a good name for all of them???

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but like I said, this is a school project where the header file is pre-written and supposed to be used as-is. I don't have a say in naming variables, just implementing them.

Comment: Agreed, but the questions are still valid - you need to understand the compiler's rules regardless of who wrote the original code.  What if you had to modify existing code written that way?  Trust me, you'll be looking at other people's code a LOT (and hopefully realize that other people will be looking at YOUR code).